# ld: archive has no table of contents file error with homebrew

Tags: homebrew

I'm trying to compile weechat,

```
%> brew upgrade weechat --debug
...

[ 86%] Built target weechat_gui_curses_normal
[ 87%] Building C object src/gui/curses/normal/CMakeFiles/weechat.dir/main.o
[ 87%] Linking C executable weechat
ld: archive has no table of contents file '../../../plugins/libweechat_plugins.a' for architecture x86_64
clang: error: unable to execute command: Segmentation fault: 11
clang: error: linker command failed due to signal (use -v to see invocation)
make[2]: *** [src/gui/curses/normal/weechat] Error 254
make[1]: *** [src/gui/curses/normal/CMakeFiles/weechat.dir/all] Error 2
make: *** [all] Error 2
bash-3.2$ exit
```

It fails with `archive has no table of contents file for architecture x86_64`, it seem to be a generic error, as it happens with mysql@5.5 and many other packages.

I also see ranlib errors

```
/usr/local/homebrew/bin/ranlib: libweechat_gui_curses_normal.a(gui-curses-term.o): unknown load command 0x32
```

Any ideas?

Answer (score 2):

Resolved.

Simple do `brew unlink binutils` or specify RANLIB=/usr/bin/ranlib.